# Knitting Beamer slides with Emacs-ESS (stop-on-error)

Tags: r, emacs, latex, knitr, ess

I am knitting the following file (note the `eRRoR()` function):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
opts_knit$set(stop_on_error=2L, message=FALSE)
options(width=40)
@

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}
<<test1>>=
eRRoR()
message("aaa")
print("test1")
@

<<test2>>=
print("test2")
@

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I’d like knitr to stop on error. But despite the `stop_on_error=2L` option the R output is as follows:

```
> local({..od <- getwd(); setwd("c:/test/"); require(knitr); knit("c:/test/ktest.rnw"); setwd(..od) })


processing file: c:/test/ktest.rnw
  |>>>>>>>>>                                                        |  14%
  ordinary text without R code

  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                              |  29%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                     |  43%
  ordinary text without R code

  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                            |  57%
label: test1
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>                   |  71%
  ordinary text without R code

  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>         |  86%
label: test2
  |>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: c:\test\ktest.tex

>
```

Apparently stop does not occur. Besides, if I PdfLaTeX the .tex output file, I get the following PDF slide:

```
Test

   eRRoR()
   ## Error:
   could not find function "eRRoR"
   message("aaa")
   ## aaa
   print("test1")
   ## [1] "test1"

   print("test2")
   ## [1] "test2"
```

The slide confirms that knitting goes on, despite the error.

It is also unclear (to me) why knitr prints “ordinary text without R code”. There is R code in those chunks. 
Also, by the output, the option `message=FALSE` doesn’t seem effective.

What am I doing wrong?
I am using ESS 12.09-1 [rev. 5167 (2012-09-24)] and knitr_0.8 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you were using an old version of `knitr`; see [FAQ 1](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md).

Comment: Oh, before posting/testing,  I ran `install.packages('knitr')`, so I was sure I was up to date. Instead I didn’t realise 'knitr' was not actually installed, since ESS was blocking it.  Thanks.